# How to save picklist value selected by user on visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce, selectlist, selectoption

I have a requirement where I am not displaying the actual salesforce picklist field on visualforce page but rather a self created selectlist with some values.
I was able to display it on visualforce page but don't know how to fetch the user selected value and store it into another field on apex class.

Here is my visualforce code to display the picklist:

```
<apex:selectList value="{!AlcoholInvolvedId}" style="width:40%;" size="1"> 

          <apex:selectOptions value="{!AlcoholInvolved}"/>  

</apex:selectList>  

<apex:commandButton id="Save" value="Save" action="{!saveAndContinue}"
```

Here is my controller class:

```
public String AlcoholInvolvedId { get;set; }
    public List<SelectOption> AlcoholInvolved{

      get

         {

            //Alcohol_Involved = new List<SelectOption>();
            List<Selectoption> Alcoholinv = new List<selectoption>();
            Alcoholinv.add(new selectOption('', '--None--'));
            Alcoholinv.add(new selectoption('', 'Yes'));
            Alcoholinv.add(new selectoption('', 'No'));

            return Alcoholinv; 

         }

       set {}


  }


 public pagereference saveAndContinue() {


    Application__c app= new Application__c(

    .........,
    Alcohol_Involved__c= AlcoholInvolvedId,
    );

      insert app;


      ............
      .............

  }
```

Here is my picklist definiton on the backend.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're setting the "value" to nothing in all the options. You need to specify a value:

```
    Alcoholinv.add(new selectOption('', '--None--'));
    Alcoholinv.add(new selectoption('Yes', 'Yes'));
    Alcoholinv.add(new selectoption('No', 'No'));
```

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for replying. I changed it to 
             Alcoholinv.add(new selectOption('', '--None--'));
             Alcoholinv.add(new selectoption('Y', 'Yes'));
             Alcoholinv.add(new selectoption('N', 'No'));

I am getting this error on visualforce now. It does not let me save the page.
Error:
id Y must be 15 characters

Comment: If it's an actual ID value, that means you're going to have to write a query to get the correct values. You can't just write 'Y' or 'N'. See [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/186222) for how to do that.

Comment: I don't know what the id would be in this case. It is a picklist in Salesforce with the global picklist values Yes and No and API names Y and N respectively.

Comment: @Student I'm pretty sure you're using the wrong field. You wouldn't get that error if it were a global picklist. Check the Alcohol_Involved__c field, I'm pretty sure it's a lookup for whatever reason.

Comment: I am not sure if global value set and global picklist are the same things or different. I have attached the screenshot of the picklist definition above.

Comment: @Student Based on that, I can only presume that the error you're actually seeing is actually referring to a different field or something. You've got something mixed up. The only way you'd get the invalid ID error is trying to assign a non-Id to a Lookup/Id field.

Comment: Ahhhhh I found where the issue was. I was displaying multiple such picklist fields on visualforce page. To capture the alcoholinvolved picklist value I had the return type string ....

public String AlcoholInvolvedId { get;set; }

But for all others, I had kept return type ID due to which it was generating error. 
Thanks for all the help.

Comment: @Student Great, I'm glad you got it sorted out.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the ID part. I was not thinking in that direction before. Thanks again.